# If I add the root to your position, why do I get 1 and 0.6 and 0?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I am studying by creating a geometry node. I use the position value and root it from the math and connect scale. So we had a scale of 1 with vertex(1,1,1), and the vertexs (1,1,0) (1,0,1) (0,1,0) had a scale of 0.6. The left vertex have a value of zero. root 1+root 1+root 1/3 shows the scale of the (1,1,1) vertex value, but not the rest. How can I calculate the same value as the file I uploaded? And I saw the math code. I don't know the function name of square root. It's in order, but there should be a square root next time, but something else comes out.

code link here
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MathBaseOperation.cpp#L423

code link I think it is geometry node math
https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_geom.c

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting a `Vector` to a `Float`

Blender's behaviour, here, is to return the mean of the X,Y,Z component coefficients:

[image]

Given that behaviour, the square root is returning the expected value.

Are you looking for the length, or some other scalar interpretation of the vector?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there's one question.
When I scale double a cube, why does the index 0 instance sphere only increase to 1.4 instead of 1 or 2? I took a screenshot that you upload and tried it, but it doubles, but it doesn't double from what I posted.

Comment: because I think root 2 is 1.4..? but index 1 2 3 sphere is 0.8 scale.